# Has anyone seen this and how can I remove it?

Tags: windows-xp, file-management

I have a folder which I'm not able to delete or open. when I check its properties, it seems like I have a drive beneath my folder:
[image: strange path]

`C:backup` is the name of the folder. Although I have a C drive, working fine, but what about this ? Does anyone know how to overcome/delete this folder? Normal delete process not working and neither is any tool.  When I try to open this, it shows an error like this:
[image]

Update:
I have tried every possible way to remove this, but it always give error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTFS supports file names that `Explorer.exe` (The [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Shell) for windows) does not. The easiest way to solve this without writing your own custom softare/script to fix it is download a Linux live CD that supports NTFS  ([ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) is a easy one to use) and delete/rename the folder from inside Linux.

Comment: hmm I will try with this.. something new for me.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an NTFS link. Try this:

1. Press [Win] + [R], enter `cmd`, click *OK*.
2. Navigate to the folder with the link: `cd /d D:\Aman`
3. Enter: `rmdir "C:backup"`.

What message are you seeing?

Comment: no help.. it gives error at console as **The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: See answer below, then.